# Spring mvc:resources mapping: URLs which don't include /api/

Tags: spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

i want to serve my angular webapp using spring mvc resources. For this purpose I want that the resource mapping only includes resources which don't start with /api/. Is this possible with spring mvc?

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/($NOT API$)**" location="/client-target/" />
```

this should be included:

- /
- /index.html,
- /images/image1.png

this should be excluded

- /api/
- /api/rest1

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Why not move all non-api resources into a folder and map that one instead?

Comment: currently i'm doing this. but i want to get rid of the prefix for all non-api resources. the angular app should be directly served with example.com.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the request URL has /api?

Comment: You could also map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/api/*` and let the `DefaultServlet` handle static resources.